# GetFeatureInfo not working in R with leaflet.extras2

Tags: r, leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo

leaflet.extras2 provides a working example for clicking on a feature and displaying its attributes; however, when I try to run it with my geoserver it doesn't display attributes, I assume there's a configuration on geoserver I have to do to make it show feature info; I can click on my layer and see info in QGIS, so that makes it a bit more bewildering as to where to start

```r
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras2)

# this doesn't show feature info
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles(group = "base") %>% 
  setView(-74, 40.78, zoom = 9) %>% 
  addWMS(
    baseUrl = "http://datamarindo.baselinux.net/geoserver/ows?",
    layers = "tiger:poly_landmarks",
    popupOptions = popupOptions(maxWidth = 600),
    checkempty = TRUE,
    options = WMSTileOptions(
      transparent = TRUE, 
      format = "image/png",
      info_format = "text/html") )

# this does show feature info
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles(group = "base") %>%
  setView(9, 50, 5) %>%
  addWMS(baseUrl = "https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/dwd/wms",
         layers = "dwd:BRD_1km_winddaten_10m",
         popupOptions = popupOptions(maxWidth = 600),
         checkempty = TRUE,
         options = WMSTileOptions(
           transparent = TRUE,
           format = "image/png",
           info_format = "text/html"))
```

Comment: My experience with this in HTML/JS environment is that this is usually consequence of CORS error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; can you orient me on how to solve this?

Comment: See https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html#enable-cors

Comment: Yes it worked! I uncommented the CORS related lines at the jetty and filter mapping as the link you provided, shut down the already running lines and started it up again; can you post the answer to mark it as solved?

Comment: Since Geoserver is not really my area and I don't know theory behind it, I'm not the right person for the answer. You can post it yourselves if you think it might help somebody else with the same problem.